# Why my jdk can't work,and before the java_home, there is a space that is not from me

Tags: java, windows, cmd

My computer is Windows 8.1,x64.I download jdk 1.8.5_20 from oracle's website.When I had setted the environment variable,I open the cmd,input the "javac" ,It can't work! But "java" is successful...
I check my environment variable,It's .
So I input the "echo %java_home%" in cmd,**I find there is a space before the string** .
I think It must couse the error! 
But I cann'r solve it!
I try any way ,such as typewriting.But cann't get a good result!

Comment: You have to set path for java in your environment variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set path for java up to bin folder

eg: `path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;`

see official [java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) here

Answer (score 0):

Open the default installation path for JDK

```
C:\Program Files\Java
```

go to below directory

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_10
```

Set the **JAVA_HOME** Variable

```
Right-click the My Computer icon on, your desktop and select Properties.
Click the Advanced tab. Click the
`Environment Variables` button. Under System Variables, click New.
Enter the variable name as **JAVA_HOME**.
Enter the variable value as the installation path for the Java Development Kit.
Click OK and Apply Changes.
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be the default installation path; you just need to know where your installation is and put that in the JAVA_HOME environment variable.

Comment: @ccoder it can be, you can give the path where it is installed.

Comment: Iknow ,my jdk is installed in the D:\Java\jdk.When I input the "echo %java_home%" in cmd,I find there is a space before the string . I think It course the error.But I don't know where the space from .

Comment: @ankur-singhal I try many ways to remove the space. But It can't work!